# What to do when I got downvotes on multiple answers in one minute?

Tags: discussion, bug, answers, downvotes

My problem is that I had several downvotes on multiple answers of mine as per the screenshot.

[image]

These happened within a minute (except for the last one). What conclusion can I get from that?

Is it only one user who's been targetting me and wants my rep to go down? If so, is it possible to prevent this kind of actions? I don't think it's possible for an user to read `10` of my answers within a minute a downvote them because of their poor quality so I'm not sure of the legitimacy of these downvotes.

If not, is it a bug? Can this come from several users? Is it bad luck?

Many thanks for lightening me out here.

Comment: A user does not like you(or because of something) and decides to downvote all your posts. You don't need to do anything. The system automatically finds these users and the serial downvotes will soon be reversed

Comment: Thanks for explaining me this and to @MartijnPieters for linking to the right question. I haven't seen it in my previous research.

Comment: The user behind this has been warned, and as others have said, the system should invalidate these votes by tomorrow.

Comment: I got the voting reversed as promised. Thanks!